# Change column values based on condition usign dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe called 'df' with two columns: 'week' and 'stock'

When column "Week" is 0, I want to change all values on colum "stock" to 0.

I can do it with base R with:

```
df[df$week == 0, "stock"] = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ifelse()`

```
 df$stock<- ifelse(df$week == 0, 0, df$stock)
```

or in `dplyr()`

```
df %>%
  mutate(stock=replace(stock, week==0, 0)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Sample data:

```
df<-data.frame("stock"=c(12334, 3456, 5678, 223232, 456, 678, 567, 1), 
                     "week"=c(0, 1,2,0,4,5,0,7))
```

Comment: I think OP is seeking a solution in **`dplyr`**.

Comment: For `dplyr` solution replace `ifelse` of base R with `if_else`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `replace` to change the values to 0 that corresponds to week==0.

```
df %>% mutate(stock=replace(stock, week==0, 0))
```